# how to pass function as an argument to a higher order function in terminal while executing a python script

Tags: python-2.7, argv

I can use argv from sys module to pass arguments to a function in terminal.
Can I pass a function as an argument to a higher order function in terminal.
If not, what can I do?
The function I have written takes a function as an argument and needs to be executed in the terminal.

Thanks

Comment: I understand all the words you're using, but not what you mean in this context. Perhaps an example of what you would like tot do would help?

Comment: You need to differentiate between the python _program_ you've written, the _python function_ you're calling within your program, and _shell commands_ you call or want to call. As it stands now, it is almost impossible to guess what your problem is.